# When DoubleTapped by mouse - discover by which button

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to allow users to double-tap a mouse's left button. But [DoubleTapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.doubletapped) is fired for *any* mouse button, and I don't see any way to discover (in the event handler) which button was clicked.

<sub>(More info: I also want to allow double-taps on a touch-screen, which is why I'm using this.)</sub>

Comment: On the double tap is there not something like (assuming `e` is your MouseEventArgs) `e.Button`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Unfortunately not.

Comment: `Tapped` is an (abstracted) gesture, not a pointer event

Answer (score 1):

The `DoubleTapped` will be preceded by a `Tapped`, and a `PointerPressed`. Handle the `PointerPressed`, query its `PointerRoutedEventArgs.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed` and remember until the `DoubleTapped` fires.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed

Keep in mind that if you rely on that, and your app is used on a tablet with no pointing device, actual tapping gestures will not have "handedness".

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find a better way.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What did you mean by "handedness"?

Comment: I might have misunderstood. Saw the fine print in your question just now ;)

When you filter the `DoubleTapped` for left clicks, what are you going to do (differently) when users double-tap on the touch screen?

handedness: tapping touch screen with fingers of the left vs. right hand

Comment: On touch-screens I won't differentiate between "types" of taps.